# Coloring matrix brackets white

Tags: graphics, matrix, text, wolfram-cloud

I have the following code in `Graphics[]`:

```
{White, Text[MatrixForm[{{2,1},{-1,1}}],{3,3}]}
```

The numbers in the matrix are showing up white, but the brackets themselves stay black. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Mathematica version and which operating system are you using? On Windows 10 with Mathematica 11.01 I see white brackets for `Graphics[{White, Text[MatrixForm[{{2, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {3, 3}]}, 
 Background -> Orange]`.

Comment: @RolfMertig, I'm using the Wolfram Development Platform, on Chrome.

Comment: That is just a small bug which apparently only shows up in the online version. Why not purchase a Student Desktop license? You will enjoy it.

Comment: @RolfMertig, I wish. Don't quite have enough money for that - I'm only in middle school. Thanks, though. Do you know if there is a workaround?

Comment: I tried, but did not find any workaround. The Wolfram Development platform kind of seems to be still under constant development. But if you really care, just call Wolfram.

Comment: @RolfMertig, thanks. I care enough to ask this question, but it's not really that big of a deal (yet) so I'll hold off on calling Wolfram for the moment. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.wolframcloud.com) using [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) fixes the incorrect coloring of the brackets.

```
Rasterize @ Graphics[{White, Text[({{2,1},{-1,1}}),{3,3}]}, Background->Gray]
```

[image: wdpOut]

Comment: Thank you, that works beautifully!